# solution to a 2nd order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I trying to solve the following differential equation. 
$$(x^2-3)y''+6xy'+4y=0$$. Should I use the power series solution or the Method of Frobenius?

Comment: You can solve by power series method around $x = 0$ as it is an ordinary point.

Comment: Now, I am having trouble with the finding the closed form of the following recurrence relation that I got. $$a_{n+2}=\frac{n^2+5n+4}{3(n+2)(n+1)}a_n$$. I also got $a_2=2a_0/3$ and $a_3=5a_1/9$. How do I solve this? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: I think this help $$a_{n+2}=\dfrac{n+4}{3(n+2)}a_{n}$$,Let $$b_{n}=\dfrac{a_{n}}{n+2}\Longrightarrow b_{n+2}=\dfrac{b_{n}}{3}$$

Comment: Sorry but I still can't figure out the pattern. Can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note
$$[(x^2-3)y'+4xy]'=(x^2-3)y''+6xy'+4y=0$$
so we have
$$(x^2-3)y'+4xy=C\Longrightarrow y'+\dfrac{4x}{x^2-3}y=\dfrac{C}{x^2-3}$$
then I think you can  use this well known
$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)\Longrightarrow y=e^{-\int P(x)dx}\left(\int Q(x)e^{\int P(x)dx}dx+C\right)$$
we have
$$y=\dfrac{1}{(x^2-3)^2}\left(c_{1}+c_{2}x(x^2-9)\right)$$
where $c_{1},c_{2}$ are constant

Comment: thank you sir. That solution is correct but I am studying Power Series solutions of DEs for our upcoming exam.