# Radius of convergence of a Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a follow-up question in a post of mine [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182370/solution-to-a-2nd-order-differential-equation#1182388). The question is to determine the radius of convergence of the differential equation $$(x^2-3)y''+6xy'+4y=0$$

Comment: You're sure you do not mean convergence radius of some solution to a DE?

Comment: I guess you are solving using a series approach and you want to check the convergence radius??

Comment: yes i am trying to solve this via series solution.

Answer (score 2):

As you solved in the commentaries of your question:

$$a_{n+2}=\frac{n^2+5n+4}{3(n+2)(n+1)}a_{n}$$

But $n^2+5n+4=(n+4)(n+1)$ so:

$$a_{n+2}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{n+4}{n+2} a_n$$

Divide by $n+4$:

$$\frac{a_{n+2}}{n+4}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{a_n}{n+2}$$

$$\frac{a_{n+2}}{(n+2)+2}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{a_n}{n+2}$$

Then if you call $b_n=\frac{a_n}{n+2}$ you will have the next relationship:

$$b_{n+2}=\frac{b_n}{3}$$

Which is a geometric progression then:

$$b_{2k}=b_0 3^{-k}$$
$$b_{2k+1}=b_1 3^{-k}$$

Comment: By the same method, $\sqrt{3}^{n+2}b_{n+2}=\sqrt{3}^nb_n$ so that $a_{n+k}=(n+2+k)\sqrt{3}^{-n}(k+2)a_k$ with $k=0,1$.

Comment: The WA formula tells you that the sequences for odd and even indices are separate geometric series with the same growth factor.

Comment: @LutzL now it's ok or not?

Comment: Yes, that is one useful form for the result.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Fuchs' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuchs%27_theorem), the radius of convergence of the *general solution* of the equation
$$
(x^2−3)y″+6xy′+4y=0
$$
around $x=x_0$, with $x_0\ne \pm\sqrt{3}$ is
$$
R=\min\big\{\lvert x_0-\sqrt{3}\rvert,\lvert x_0+\sqrt{3}\rvert\big\}.
$$